# What is the purpose of 'using' keyword in Scala?

Tags: scala

What's the meaning of `using` in the following snippet?

```
case Event(Task1('name', num, categ), _) => goto(RunAll) using ToAdd(num, categ)
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not a keyword. It is simply calling a method on whatever `goto(RunAll)` returns (`goto` isn't a keyword either in case you are wondering, it's just a function declared somewhere in your code).

Dots and parentheses when calling methods are optional in scala, so the snipped you showed can be written as

```
 case Event(Task1('name', num, categ), _) => goto(RunAll).using(ToAdd(num, categ))
```